# Exported Docker image tar is not identical after being extracted and recreated

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, npm, tar

For an application, I need the ability to export images from Docker, extract them from their tar files, and then recreate these images to identical tar files that can be imported without any change.

However, when I extract an image tar, and then IMMEDIATELY, without any further action, attempt to create a new, identical tar (e.g. the root is the same in both), the resulting file slightly differs in size.

Verification:

- Using `sha256sum` on both files result in a different hash.
- After extracting both archives, comparison on the resulting folders shows they are perfectly identical. Verified with both `diff` and Meld.

Steps used:

For image export: `docker image save {image_name} >{tar_name} && mkdir >{extract_folder}`

For archive operations, npm package `tar` is used:

```
tar.extract({
    file: {tar_file_path},
    cwd: {extract_folder},
    mtime: date, // a timestamp set before running any script
    preserveOwner: true,
})
/* */
tar.create({
    file: {new_tar_file_path},
    cwd: {extract_folder},
    mtime: date, // same as above
}, [''])
```

Using `dhex` also shows significant hex-level differences, but it's not clear on a high level, what constitutes as a difference.

What other steps are necessary in the creation of the new archive to ensure it's identical to the original?

No compression was applied at any point in the running.

Comment: If you need to change an image, the standard practice is to update your application source code and/or its `Dockerfile` and re-run `docker build`.  What are you trying to change with this save/modify/load sequence?  Why is important for the reassembled image to be byte-for-byte identical?

Comment: @DavidMaze the images are not modified. I just need to know the exact content of each and every image and being able to create an IDENTICAL, importable archive. The application is confidential so I prefer not to explain further details.